# How to handle a Subscription/Observable inside a Jasmine test?

Tags: jasmine, rxjs, observable

I am trying to listen to changes of an `observable` that resides inside a shared function that I would use to test multiple similar items.

Where should I initialize the `subscription` in order to make it available to each `it()` block?

This is an extract of the code I have been testing:

```
describe('some test', () => {
  // service is an external service injected earlier
  const contrast = () => service.contrast$;
  sharedTest('contrast', contrast);

  function sharedTest(statePropName: string, observableInstance: any): void {
    describe(`${statePropName}$ observable`, () => {
      let serviceProp: Subject<any>;
      let count: number = 0;
      let value: any = null;

      beforeEach(() => {
        serviceProp = observableInstance();
      });

      // serviceProp is not defined yet
      serviceProp.subscribe(res => {
        count++;
        value = res;
      });

      it('should stream the initial default value', () => {
        expect(count).toBe(0);
        expect(value).toBe(null);
      });

      it('should stream the correct value after emitting one', () => {
        // serviceProp subscription is not working here
        serviceProp.emit(50);
        expect(count).toBe(1);
        expect(value).toBe(50);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I also tried to initialize the subscription inside a `beforeAll()` but doesn't work either.

Any suggestion on how to properly address this? Thanks

Comment: I can only say that's a terrible idea, you don't control the way jasmine will process the tests, the subscription is asynchronous. Each test should be independant so you should manually start with a predefined state before each test or at the beginning of each test

Comment: I don't understand if the _terrible idea_ is to use `sharedTest()` to test multiple functions or the way the test is done inside `sharedTest()`. Would you elaborate more on that? Thanks

Comment: unit tests should be independables.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova do you have any reference material where they suggest to avoid such approach? I read about avoiding code duplication here https://juristr.com/blog/2014/10/avoid-test-code-duplication-jasmine/ ... what do you think?

Comment: each test can impact another, which is not a good practice, it s actually exactly as coding, write code that doesn't interfere with another code. But if you want to do it that way, nothing prevents you from doing it, it just makes it way more complicated to debug

Answer (score 0):

[Practices to avoid, or "anti-patterns" (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Best_practices) :

- Dependencies between test cases. A test suite where test cases are
  dependent upon each other is brittle and complex. Execution order
  should not be presumed. Basic refactoring of the initial test cases
  or structure of the UUT causes a spiral of increasingly pervasive
  impacts in associated tests.
- Interdependent tests. Interdependent tests can cause cascading false
  negatives. A failure in an early test case breaks a later test case
  even if no actual fault exists in the UUT, increasing defect analysis
  and debug efforts.*

Comment: mmm thanks for your feedback but
(A) it's not the answer to my post question so I would rather see this as the answer to my comment.
(B) I don't see all the tests as dependent from each other. They just depend on an external function which is not a test itself.
You're probably right anyway, I just don't think those 2 cases fit in my example above.

Comment: sorry, i did not get you. in this case you can just move the function outside of describe block in the file. it will be available to all it and describe functions.